# GETSTATE weblogic Command takes too long, any recommendation?

Tags: java, linux, weblogic, weblogic11g, getstate

I make a script to check if server is up or not, incase of it's down or not responding, i restart it. i use GETSTATE command

```
    java weblogic.Admin -url t3://localhost:7001 -username weblogic -password weblogic GETSTATE managedServer1
```

i run it every minute to ensure the server is running, but it takes too long some times, although server is up and handeling requests.

if it help, using http instead of t3?  if it's not related to used protocol what can i do to make it takes less time, Or how can i check server is really running and handeling requests or not ?

Comment: Use the PING or CONNECT commands instead of GETSTATE

Comment: Thanks for replying, ping or connect doesn't help I think, port can be opened but it doesn't mean server is up.

Comment: Both commands will work only if the server is up and listening to incoming connections.

Comment: @Emmanuel Thanks a lot for your help, i try the commands, when server is down and up, i can't recoginize any difference. here is the repsonse when its up : `RTT = ~59 milliseconds, or ~59 milliseconds/packet` and here is where is down   `RTT = ~34 milliseconds, or ~34 milliseconds/packet`

Comment: if the server is down, none of both commands will return a success. Are you sure to ping the good server ?